# Enable Global Theming with Emotion?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I have followed https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/546 in which Emotion's author Kye mentions a solution although I don't understand it completely.

So I made a small [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r76p996zym) that implements the details provided in the issue. How can I make `background-color` theme work in `injectGlobal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The complete solution can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/r76p996zym or https://github.com/deadcoder0904/emotion-global-theming

Make a `theme.js` file containing your application themes

## theme.js

```
export const theme = {
  LIGHT: {
    textColor: "black",
    bgColor: "white"
  },
  DARK: {
    textColor: "white",
    bgColor: "black"
  }
};
```

Wrap `Global` Component in `withTheme` & it should take a `theme` prop

## Global.js

```
import React from "react";
import { injectGlobal } from "react-emotion";
import { withTheme } from "emotion-theming";

class Global extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.theme.bgColor !== prevProps.theme.bgColor) {
      window.document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.props.theme.bgColor;
    }
    if (this.props.theme.textColor !== prevProps.theme.textColor) {
      window.document.body.style.color = this.props.theme.textColor;
    }
  }

  render() {
    injectGlobal`
      color: ${this.props.theme.textColor};
      background-color: ${this.props.theme.bgColor};
    `;
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
  }
}

export default withTheme(Global);
```

And then wrap your `App` component with `Global` component. As `Global` component requires `theme` it should be wrapped in `ThemeProvider`

## index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "emotion-theming";

import Global from "./injectGlobal";
import { theme } from "./theme";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLight: true,
    title: "Light Theme",
    theme: theme.LIGHT
  };

  _toggleTheme = () => {
    const { isLight } = this.state;
    const title = isLight ? "Dark Theme" : "Light Theme";
    const newTheme = isLight ? theme.DARK : theme.LIGHT;
    this.setState({
      isLight: !isLight,
      title,
      theme: newTheme
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { title, theme } = this.state;
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Global>
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <button onClick={this._toggleTheme}>Toggle Theme</button>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Global>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Note - This answer is only valid until Emotion 10 releases & API changes. If Emotion version is less than 10, then use this solution.

Answer (score 16):

Update for folks who uses emotion 10:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useTheme, ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming'
import { css, Global } from '@emotion/core'

const GlobalStyles = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  return (
    <Global styles={css`
      body {
        background: ${theme.bg};
      }
    `} />
  )
}


const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={{ bg: 'tomato' }}>
    <main>
      <h1>Hi</h1>
      <GlobalStyles />
    </main>
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```